# I have a folder with code, I need to bind it to svn repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I copied some code on to a new machine and now I need to add that code to the svn source control repository. If I do a checkout, will it overwrite the files in the existing folder or check what exists, add it to source control and only update what is out of date? I am doing this over my internet connection to my office in another city, and the code is extensive and we have to deal with crippling data caps (10 gig a month) so I can't just do a checkout of all new code from the server, which is why I copied the code on to a storage media to put on my local working machine. I am an ex MS TFS user, so svn is relatively new.

I hope I have worded this question clearly enough, it feels a little clunky.

*update*
Ok, so I have an update, svn seems to update the info icons a little slowly, if I go 1 child deep from the main parent folder I can see the subfolders are linked to svn, but not the parent folder... Any reason for that?

Comment: do you have .svn folders copied as well?

Comment: I copied the whole bang shoot.

Answer (score 1):

Check in your changes in the repository. If no conflicts exist, it will update the repository just by moving the changed parts of the code to the server. In the case of any conflicts, find the files that cause the problem. Get them and merge your changes into them, then do a check-in (or commit).